# Redis replication at key level

Tags: redis, replication

We are using redis. We have two set of data. One set of data(Assume it is using the prefix **redis:local:** eg: *redis:local:key1*) is used by the main application and no need of replication.

Another set of data (Prefix **redis:replicate:** eg: *redis:replicate:key2*) is used by the main application and should be replicated to slave redis instances.

I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to configure redis to replicate only keys with prefix **redis:replicate:**?
2. If that is not possible, Is it possible to configure redis to replicate only one database? We will store the first set of data in *database-0* and the second set of data in *database-1*. So we have to replicate only *database-1*.

Currenly, we are running two instances of redis to solve the issue.

Comment: I have similar issue. I am thinking of modifying twitter nutcracker to do that. Did you finally find an easier solution?

Comment: @gtato don't remember now. They may have implemented namespace now!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis only supports replication of whole instances. Limiting replication to a key prefix or database is not possible.

Running two instances of Redis is simplest and reliable option.
Another way would be to write a custom replication program which is difficult and failure prone in comparison.

There is also another question concerning replication of only one database: [Replicate a single Redis database from an instance that has multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819387/replicate-a-single-redis-database-from-an-instance-that-has-multiple-databases)

Comment: It will be useful if you added any reference url.

Comment: Since selective replication does not exist, [the documentation](http://redis.io/topics/replication) does not mention any of it, so there is nothing to reference.